# Urls opening through Hangouts app showing Redirect Notice in Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am making a browser kind of application. I am trying to open the following url in my app.
http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm

If I am opening this url from Whatsapp or Gmail, then it loads perfectly fine in my app, but if I open the same url from hangouts app, then it shows me Redirect Notice as shown in the below picture.

[image]

But the same url is opening perfectly fine in Chrome app.

Actually, the url which I receive in my app gets changed to the following url:
https://www.google.com/url?q=http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm

Note that this issue is not happening on all devices. I found this issue happening on Vivo phone which has Android Lollipop installed. Anybody else faced this issue?